# Erro Internal Error Server UID of script is smaller than min_uid

Tags: php

Quando eu entro na página que estou desenvolvendo aparece o seguinte erro:

> Internal Server Error
>
> UID of script "/home/httpd/html/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> suPHP 0.7.2

Alguém sabe o que pode ser e como resolver?

Comment: Parece ser problema de permissão, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9711085/1342547

Comment: Aqui era falta de espaço no servidor. Estava hospedado na Locaweb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717056/1518921)

Isto parece um problema com o [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html).

> Change the user and group of your script to the user running your
>   webserver process. So if you're running an Apache with user www-data
>   for example, change to:

Altere o usuário e o grupo do seu script para o usuário que esta rodando o seu processo de *servidor web*. Por exemplo, se você estiver executando um Apache com o usuário www-data por exemplo, mude para:

```
chown www-data:www-data /home/.../public_html/index.php
```

Ou altere todos arquivos de uma vez:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/.../public_html/
```

Se você ainda estiver com este problema após mudar o usuário e grupo então provavelmente suPHP esta usando o valor padrão de `min_uid = 100`, o UID de www-data deve ser menor que 100.

Pra corrigir isto você pode trocar o `min_uid` nas configurações do `suPHP` pro correspondente do UID do www-data:

Pra editar:

```
vi /etc/suphp/suphp.conf

min_uid = <UID of www-data>
```

Se você não tem acesso SSH e isto for uma hospedagem ou outro tipo de servidor online, talvez você tenha que entrar em contato com o suporte ou com o administrador do servidor.

Comment: Aqui era falta de espaço no servidor. Estava hospedado na Locaweb.

Comment: @LucasBustamante não necessáriamente, isto provavelmente que ocorreu contigo foi o que eu chamo de efeito colateral, a falta de espaço pode afetar qualquer serviço que necessite "escrever", afetaria até sessões no PHP. Ou seja um coisa desencadeou um problema e outras coisas.

Comment: Sim mas, em termos práticos, pode ajudar quem hospeda na Locaweb, pois descobri recentemente que ele dá esse erro quando não paga o servidor, também...

Comment: @LucasBustamante por isso chamo de efeito colateral, a falta de espaço poderia ter afetado outro serviço se acaso a locaweb funcionasse com outro tipo de configuração, ou seja afetou neste caso "especifico" seu devido a configuração "especifica" do tipo de serviço que contratou da locaweb (ela tem vários diferentes com configs diferentes). Não dá pra eu abordar o assunto sobre falta de espaço pois é algo que pode ocorrer só em situações especificas e **"não praticas"**. Mas obrigado pela informação de qualquer forma.

Comment: Pessoal, tive um problema parecido com esse ontem. O site do cliente estava hospedado na Locaweb e ocorreu por falta de pagamento. Fiz o acordo agora com o servidor, paguei o boleto e o site voltou a funcionar.

Comment: @ÁllanFidelisToledo como eu comentei acima para o Lucas, que reportou a mesma situação que você disse, isso é um caso especifico, provavelmente é uma estratégia dessa hospedagem especifica, não é um problema técnico, é só uma "maneira" que eles inventaram de bloquear com mais facilidade (para eles) clientes inadimplentes, mas não é algo comum em outras hospedagens e nem é o foco de sites de perguntas voltados ao lado "técnico".